# Should I include bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css together?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Should I include two css file or one is enough?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" media="all" />
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: Its no more necessary from version 3

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Bootstrap 2**

You should include both, the first one defines all the styles for html elements whilst the second one adds responsiveness to the layout.

**Bootstrap 3**

Only one css file will be included.

Happy coding!

Comment: Its no more necessary from version 3

Answer (score 58):

Both of the files should be included as of **Bootstrap 2**.

---

But with **Bootstrap 3** only one css file will be included.

> Responsive CSS is no longer separate and all responsive features are
>   now compiled into the core bootstrap.css file near. Separate files are
>   no longer required, and have thus been removed

Source: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6342

Edit: If you want to include bootstrap 3 css you can use this CDN version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
   href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the official [Twitter Bootstrap download helper](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) in order to have one CSS file named `bootstrap.css` (resp. `bootstrap.min.css`) which will contain the following CSS parts:

- Scaffolding
- Base CSS
- Components
- JS Components
- Miscellaneous
- Responsive

Comment: No more necessary from version 3