# Where is bootstrap-responsive.css?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I know that by default the bootstrap doesn't come with the file, but after I customized (I've selected all the responsive features!) I still can't see the file. At the docs, it says that I should do this on head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But the truth is that I don't even have the folder assets. What I do have is:

```
\bootstrap
    \img
    \css
    \js
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Since Bootstrap 3 you don't need responsive.css anymore. Because it is inside default bootstrap.css.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16379181/429938

Comment: This is no longer true for Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 21):

Download http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip
and uncompress.

```
\bootstrap\css\bootstrap-responsive.css

\bootstrap\css\bootstrap-responsive.min.css
```

Comment: I'm sorry to respond only now. Anyway, thank you for your response back then =)

Answer (score 5):

look here
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

> Bootstrap doesn't include responsive features by default at this time
>   as not everything needs to be responsive. Instead of encouraging
>   developers to remove this feature, we figure it best to enable it as
>   needed.

So if you need bootstrap-responsive.css, you should download it from bootstrap-source, 
from here for example:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html

Comment: I'm sorry to respond only now. Anyway, thank you for your response back then =)

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use directly as below:

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I'm sorry to respond only now. Anyway, thank you for your response back then =)

Answer (score 1):

They moved it to a different directory. Try this:

```
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
https://ci.apache.org/projects/openejb/examples-generated/moviefun/src/main/webapp/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css.html
```

1. make a file name `bootstrap-reponsive.css` on your CSS folder
2. copy all these to that file.
3. give link to that file on your HTML code

Comment: The resource is not found.