# Can't find bootstrap-responsive.css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to use bootstrap for a little website I am working on
I'm using bower to add each client library I need (jquery, angular, bootstrap ...).
I've installed bootstrap (with bower install), but I cannot find (among the downloaded files) the "bootstrap-responsive.css" file.

My question is : Is it possible to get this file using bower, or do I have to get it some other way (like explained here : [Where is bootstrap-responsive.css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687233/where-is-bootstrap-responsive-css)) ?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's baked in automatically in v3. So you get it by default when including the main CSS file.  By contrast there is a guide to making it non-responsive in the 'Getting Started' area of the Bootstrap website.

Comment: they should probably update their website then ... from http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive: "_Heads up! Bootstrap doesn't include responsive features by default at this time as not everything needs to be responsive. Instead of encouraging developers to remove this feature, we figure it best to enable it as needed._"

Comment: They did, the new URL is http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive and it describes how to disable the baked-in responsiveness.  The URL you have posted is from the legacy website supporting the old version (v2.3.2).

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 3.0 is responsive by default.

An article published back in December made clear what the Bootstrap team works on for the new major update and the announced improvements were these:

- Change the Bootstrap URL Compile all LESS code, as well as the
- responsive styles, all in a single CSS file Drop support for IE7
- Switch to the MIT license instead of the Apache Drop the *-wip branch
- style of development Accelerate versioning Improve responsive CSS
- Centralize community efforts

See http://designmodo.com/twitter-bootstrap-3/ or https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342