# What is different between bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

What is different between bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css?
I got confused which one to use to make responsive websites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I include bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455222/should-i-include-bootstrap-css-and-bootstrap-responsive-css-together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both and the responsive css has the rules for the responsive stuff. Like the layout for different view port sizes:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```