# what is really the difference and advantage using bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I m designing responsive web page layout suing `bootstrap 3.x.x` and i see that grid design is supported  in `bootstrap.css` and `bootstarp-responsive.css` , when i  look my code after render on browser , i see that responsive css override the one default css of bootstrap.

And , i would like to know what can do about it ,

1.Do you really need to add `bootstarp-responsive.css` when ever u use bootstrap page and what is exactly the diffrence it will make ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687233/where-is-bootstrap-responsive-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Bootstrap 3 you no longer need Bootstrap-responsive. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/16379181/3421811 for greater detail